# How to trigger kernel driver _exit function

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

I'm testing a driver that I've built into the kernel and would like to verify that my `DRIVER_exit` command functions as expected. The `DRIVER_init` command executes automatically during boot, I assume the `exit` command does the same on shutdown. When testing the driver as a module I utilized `insmod` and `rmmod` to execute `_init` and `_exit` functions. Is there any command to trigger the exit function prematurely similar to `rmmod`? Alternatively is there a system log I can look at to see how my last shutdown sequence went?

Comment: If the driver is not too long, include it in the question if possib;e. Otherwise, including a link to the driver would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `printk` logging in your _init and _exit functions?  BTW, a quick google search for `printk in module _exit function` shows a few questions on Stack Overflow that might be relevant.  This question probably belongs on Stack Overflow, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your driver is compiled statically in the kernel, it is not possible to call the exit function of your module because it is will be excluded from the kernel at linking time. Have a look at the __exit and __exitused definitions in [include/linux/init.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h#L86)

Comment: Nevertheless one may put some logic in to `unbind` (`->remove()` in the driver) callback.

Comment: Yeah, he explicitly asked about the exit function of the driver that he already has. But indeed, one may still unbind the driver at anytime as long as the .remove callback is present.